# is it possible to reference a new actionresult to an existing view in mvc 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Im a fresher using .NET

I have 1 view and then I create a new controller..
can I use that existing view to display the data from my new controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just pass that View to your controller:

```
return View("View", ModelHere);
```

If your View or CSHTML file is Record.cshtml, you can pass it like:

```
return View("Record", ModelHere)
```

or

```
return View("Record");
```

If its on different folder and still under View Folder:

```
 return View("../FolderName/Record");
```

Comment: Additional note - since it seems likely that the OP will  need to pass data to their view, they needs to make sure that their new controller creates a compatible object for the view. The view can't just take in any object you pass to it (unless you're using object or dynamic, for some reason...), it has to follow the type restrictions. Failing to do this, will result in runtime exceptions being thrown from the new controller (but the old controller will continue to work normally). Tools like Resharper can identify these issues while in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can have several controllers using the same view. All you have to do is to mention the name of your view in the return statement of the controller.

```
 return View("ViewName");
```

Comment: Hi..is it the name of the view file ?